# I have python application running on ECS fargate with xray-daemon but not showing traces or service map

Tags: aws-xray

I read on internet that xray sidecar don't require to instrument source code

xray daemon running as sidecar.

Have open port 2000 UDP from anywhere

Opened port 443 outbound to reach xray endpoint.

Attached X-ray write access IAM Policy.

Still it's not added Traces or showing service maps.
Do I must require to instrument with X-ray library?

Answer (score 0):

XRay user does have to instrument the application, refer to [an easy solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-python-patching.html)

Alternatively, for new user we recommend onboard ADOT, which provides [auto-instrumentation solution](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/python-sdk/auto-instr).